# Quelle est la différence de sens entre « au moins » et « au bas mot » ?

Tags: sens, locutions

Est-ce que les deux phrases veulent dire à peu près la même chose ? Pour ce qui est de « **au moins** » et « **du moins** », je constate que l'usage des deux est loin d'être pareil, mais qu'en est-il de « **au moins** » et « **au bas mot** » ? Merci.

> « Vous avez tué cinq innocents. **Au bas mot**. »

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela veut dire la même chose, mais l'expression *au bas mot* est une expression imagée qui connote l'idée que le locuteur est en train de réaliser une estimation, ce qui la rend inappropriée dans certains contextes. Par exemple

> Cette maison vaut un million d'euros au bas mot.

signifie "je ne sais pas vraiment combien cette maison vaut, mais c'est au moins un million d'euros".

Dans les contextes où "au moins" n'est pas utilisé pour une estimation, on ne peut pas vraiment utiliser *au bas mot*, par exemple dans les phrases suivates :

> Sur l'autoroute, il faut rouler à 40 km/h au moins.
>
> J'essaie de manger des légumes au moins 3 fois par jour.

EDIT: Une autre différence est que *au bas mot* connote que la quantité véritable est impressionnante ou surprenante, alors que *au moins* est plus neutre et n'a pas de telle connotation.

Comment: Elucidating answer. +1.

Comment: @qoba          On n'est donc censé utiliser « au bas mot » que quand on dit un nombre au hasard, c'est ça ? Merci.

Comment: C'est utilisable quand on parle d'une estimation inférieure seulement, pas complètement au hasard.